# Line break during html() event on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

[image]

I'm trying to change text on an element when another element is clicked. This works fine on Chrome, but in Firefox, the event forces the last word to break into the second line momentarily before settling within the first.

I have no idea why this happens. The code I use is:

> $('.arrow_box').html(getMessage();

where getMessage() just retrieves the text from an array.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: $('.arrow_box').html(getMessage(); I can see that your html code is not having completed bracket. Can you check on it?

Comment: change $('.arrow_box').html(getMessage()); no closing bracket.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it does in the actual code. I just didn't copy it properly for here. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can prevent this using CSS

```
.arrow_box{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space for more info on the `white-space` property

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
.arraw_box { 
    white-space: nowrap
}
```